# Customising ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Does anybody have any experience working with the Android ActionBar?
I am currently working on a project which involves me having to utilise the actionbar, however I am running into a lot of difficulties.

At present I am trying to create something similar to the image below:

[image]

I used ms paint to draw in the item marked with the red circle. Does anybody have any idea how I might achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8800127/1012284

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom view (Layout for your above view) and set it to your ActionBar using setCustomView function.